# Custom tcolorbox and varwidth environments

Tags: environments, tcolorbox

I would like to combine the *tcolorbox* environment and *varwidth* environment into one single environment, but I'm having trouble.  I'd like to be able to achieve the following:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[flush right,title=Answer,hbox]
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
            Whatever text blah blah blah
    \end{varwidth}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

by using:

```
\begin{myenvironment}
    Whatever text blah blah blah
\end{myenvironment}
```

I tried defining the environment as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myenvironment}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}[flush right,title=Answer,hbox]
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
}{
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \end{varwidth}
}
```

but I'm getting loads of errors.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem. A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, include any necessary packages and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. At the moment we have to guess what you are doing because we cannot reproduce your problem from the code that you have given us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just use the [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) `fitting` library? In more detail, the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{fitting}

\newtcolorbox{myenvironment}{
  fit,flush right,title=Answer,hbox,left=0mm,right=0mm
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{myenvironment}
      Whatever text blah blah blah
  \end{myenvironment}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

You can further adjust the spacing , colours etc in the usual [tcolorbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) ways.